# How can I rewrite a break statement in a for loop using only if/else statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, break

I am working through a Javascript course and am currently learning about break statements in for loops. The course text says that I can instead write if/else statements instead of using the break statement to accomplish the same thing. I have a solution, but it was difficult to come up with and it seems like a rather inelegant solution too.

Code using the break statement:

```js
var numsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// stipulation: do not print out elements with index value greater than 2
for (var i = 0; i < numsArray.length; i++) {
  if (i > 2) {
    console.log('FOR LOOP BROKEN');
    break; // ends loop
  }
  console.log('current index:', i);
  console.log('current element:', numsArray[i]);
  console.log('==============');
}
```

Code rewritten to only use if/else statements:

```js
var numsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// stipulation: do not print out elements with index value greater than 2
for (var i = 0; i < numsArray.length; i++) {
  if (i > 2) {
    console.log('FOR LOOP BROKEN');
    i = numsArray.length; // ends loop
  } else {
    console.log('current index:', i);
    console.log('current element:', numsArray[i]);
    console.log('==============');
  }
}
```

This works, but I feel like there should be a better way to make sure the loop doesn't run the statements after the if statement block. Is there?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that'd be the way to do it. But as you noticed, it looks kind of ugly. `break` makes a lot more sense in this situation (IMO). If you happen to be in a function that does nothing else, you can also `return`.

Comment: So you're saying that you lack confidence in how `else` works?

Comment: Also note that the two pieces of code are very much different in meaning. If the first sample used `continue` and not `break`, they'd be the same. However, as rewritten, the second loop will continue to iterate.

Comment: @Pointy `i = numsArray.length; // ends loop`

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah, right. Well that's pretty ugly, I agree.

Comment: But here you use `i = numsArray.length;` instead of `break`, not `if/else` instead of `break`

Comment: If the question is about this specific case, then the `for` condition could be changed to `i <= 2 && i < numsArray.length`. Then put the "BROKEN" message after the loop.

Comment: TBH this is silly, break exists for a reason. Just break.

Comment: It is also off topic here. The  code works = no problem.

Comment: If you know that you will exit the loop the general and clear approach is to create a variable boolean isLoopOver and put it in (!isLoopOver && i < numsArray.length).

Comment: @Pointy Nowhere did I say or imply that. I said the version with else works.

Comment: @trincot Is this site really only for when your code doesn't work?

Comment: @CalIrvine I'm about finding different ways to do things. I thought if it was mentioned, it was worth mentioning, but clearly, I'm having trouble figuring out why and so are a lot of people.  I guess the consensus is that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @letmeeatbrioche, no, you can ask other questions too (like on algorithms, tools, ...), but when your question is about "a better way", or performance, or best practice,... when you already have working code, then [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit.

Comment: @trincot Oh, I wasn't aware of Code Review, thank you.